# Opening a popup window centered and a specific width and height

Tags: javascript

I am trying to have a window popup when someone clicks on an album from a select option.  I can get a new tab to pop up but have not been able to get a new window to pop up and center.  Here is my code that I have used:

```
function popup(pageURL, title, popupWidth, popupHeight) 
{
    var left = (screen.width / 2) - (popupWidth / 2);
    var top = (screen.height / 2) - (popupHeight / 2);
    var targetPop = window.open(pageURL, title, 'toolbar=no, location=no,directories=no,status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=YES, resizable=YES, copyhistory=no,width=' + popupWidth + ', height=' + popupHeight + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);
}
```

I then call the function popup() when you select a specific album from a select box like this:

```
popup('http://www.google.com', 'googlePopup',700,600)
```

Im using google just for testing purpose.

Can get a window to open with google, however it opens in a new tab rather then a new window centered

Comment: which one you want newtab or centered Popupwindow?

Comment: centered popup window

Answer (score 0):

Whether a pop-up opens in a new window or in a new tab depends on user preferences. You cannot change this behavior.

If you want a pop-up that opens center screen, I suggest you use a pure HTML-solution and put a layer on top of your page. You could use a library like jQuery UI for that (or any other available)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this, Added `screenX` and `screenY`

```
  var targetPop = window.open(pageURL, title, 'toolbar=no, location=no,directories=no,status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=YES, resizable=YES, copyhistory=no,width=' + popupWidth + ', height=' + popupHeight + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left+",screenX=" + left + ",screenY="
                + top);
```